# Replacing square-root term in optimization constraint?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am implementing an optimization problem using semi-definite problem. One of my constraints is of following form

$$trace(A*X)- (k * trace(A*X))+ (k * \sqrt{trace(B*X)})==0$$

where k is a constant, $A$ and $B$ are constant complex hermitian matrices and $X$ is $m*m$ complex, hermitian semi definite matrix optimization variable.

It can be seen that the last terms $\sqrt{trace(B*X)}$ is a problematic term. Since, I am writing my code using YALMIP, which is an external toolbox of MATLAB, sqrt on complex variable is not allowed in that toolbox. Is there any way to rewrite that particular term using some convex optimization tools so that I can implement it easily in YALMIP?

Comment: Why do you think a nonlinear equality constraint is convex to begin with?

Comment: I didn't say that the posted equation is convex. If I remove the sqrt term from the equation, then the equation is becomes linear in terms of X and thus convex. That's the reason I am asking is there any mathematical way to rewrite the sqrt term such that my equation become linear again and the sqrt term is handled separately in such a way that I maintain the convexity of my problem.